# Convert Automatic Migrations to Explicit Migrations after the fact

Tags: .net, entity-framework, visual-studio, entity-framework-6

Is there a way to convert an existing Automatic Migration into a code first migration?

I'm dealing with a database with an extensive migration history containing both Automatic and Code based Migrations. One of the Automatic migrations is preventing `Update-Database` from generating a new database without using `-Force` and I'd like to edit it if possible so I can retain the migration history. (The classic Add/Drop calls instead of RenameColumn).

**Is there a way that I can generate an Explicit code migration from this automatic migration in the middle of the migration history?**

Or should I just cut my losses, delete the `__MigrationHistory`table, delete my Migrations, and create a new initial migration and a new init script start fresh?

I'm using Visual Studio 2013/2015, Entity Framework 6.

Comment: I eventually did just that: Cut my losses, made a new initial migration, deleted all the old migrations and started my migration history anew.